# Python check dtype of array - float or complex

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

How can I check that a numpy array if of float or complex dtype? For simple examples the following checks all work fine.

```
# these are True
a = np.zeros(10)
a.dtype == float
a.dtype == np.float
a.dtype == np.float64

b = np.zeros(10,dtype=complex)
b.dtype == complex
b.dtype == np.complex
b.dtype == np.complex128
```

However, I have an array of dtype `dtype('>f8')`. None of the previous comparisons identifies it as a float array. As far as I can see the endianness (> vs. <) is the issue there. Is there any general function to check whether the array is float or complex with all variations?

Comment: `np.iscomplexobj` tests the `type` of the `dtype`: `issubclass(arr.dtype.type, np.complexfloating)`.  The base dtypes have several levels of subclassing, so simple '==' tests don't always work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try `numpy.isrealobj()` and `np.iscomplexobj()`?

Your examples:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(10)
print(np.isrealobj(a)) # -> True
print(np.iscomplexobj(a)) # -> False

b = np.zeros(10,dtype=complex)
print(np.isrealobj(b)) # -> False
print(np.iscomplexobj(b)) # -> True

c=np.zeros(10, dtype='>f8')
print(np.isrealobj(c)) # -> True
print(np.iscomplexobj(c)) # -> False
```

The documentation states for `np.isrealobj(x)`:

> Return True if x is a not complex type or an array of complex numbers.
>
> The type of the input is checked, not the value. So even if the input
>   has an imaginary part equal to zero, `isrealobj` evaluates to False
>   if the data type is complex.

There is also the possibility to check by value: `np.isreal`and `np.iscomplex`.

Does this help?

Comment: Definitely helps, even for empty arrays, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are fully satisfied with my answer, please consider to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `all()` function combined with the `isinstance()` function.

The `all()` function returns True if all the elements of a list is true, and you can check if every number in your numpy array is a float using `isinstance()`. Since `isinstance()` considers '>f8' as a float, the comparaisons doesn't raise the problem that you had.

Here is what it looks like :

```
b = np.zeros(10,dtype='>f8')
all(isinstance(x, float) for x in b)
```

---

Output :

```
True
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why the program should not test `type(b[0]) == float` or something like that. +1 anyway.

Comment: Is there also a solution for empty arrays, i.e. `np.array([])`? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: Using `np.isrealobj()` works also for empty arrays: `np.isrealobj(np.array([]))` is True and `np.isrealobj(np.array([], dtype=complex))` is False.

Comment: @bproxauf all(b) returns true when true if b is empty there is no way around this just using the all function. But you could add a condition like so `all(b) and len(b) != 0` to get the appropriate result

Comment: Checking the type of all elements of an array is not a good idea: Numpy guarantees that all elements have the same type (except for object arrays), and that is the main reason where the performance of numpy comes from.